# Added column to dataset not allowing value to be set

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

So I have a typed dataset which has already been populated from the database.  when displaying a particular Windows Form I want to add a few temporary columns to this dataset to be displayed in a grid.

The problem is I can add these columns fine, but whenever I try to set a value to one of my programmatically added columns, the value does not change, and the row state of the row remains unchanged.

```
//DataSet has already been filled from database
private void AddColumns( MyTypedDataSet DataSet )
{
   DataSet.Table1.Columns.Add( "newCol", typeof(double));

   foreach( MyTypedDataSet.Table1Row dataRow in DataSet.Table1 )
      dataRow["newCol"] = 123.4;
}
```

If I open up the watch window, the `dataRow.RowState` remains `Unchanged` throughout the foreach loop.

And if I open up the DataSet Visualizer after the loop runs, the column for every row is still DBNull

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to commit yours data before add modification (AcceptChanges)

```
            DataSet.Table1.AcceptChanges();

           foreach( MyTypedDataSet.Table1Row dataRow in DataSet.Table1 )
           {
                dataRow["newCol"] = 123.4;
           }
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference.  Values are still DBNull.

Comment: Have you tried with GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified) on your DataTable

Comment: All of the data rows have a row state of unchanged, so calling get changes( DataRowState.Modified ) returns null.